# How to make a drop down menu using xslt and xml?

Tags: xml, list, xslt, drop-down-menu, menu

The problem is, when I save the code for the dropdown list in the .xsl file, after opening my .xml file in the browser I get the output of all the text from the .xml file appearing on the screen. All the output that I had before working on the dropdown list is gone and replaced by a massive block of text. I need the drop down list to appear with all the things I edited using xsl.

XML code for drop down list:

```
<selectlist>
    <selectName num="1">
        <memberName>Slash</memberName>
    </selectName>
    <selectName num="2">
        <memberName>Axl</memberName>
    </selectName>
    <selectName num="3">    
       <memberName>Duff</memberName>
    </selectName>
    <selectName num="4">
       <memberName>Izzy</memberName>
    </selectName>
    <selectName num="5">
        <memberName>Steven</memberName>
    </selectName>
    <selectName num="6">
        <memberName>Matt</memberName>
    </selectName>
    <selectName num="7">    
        <memberName>Gilby</memberName>
    </selectName>
    <selectName num="8">
        <memberName>Ashba</memberName>
    </selectName>
    <selectName num="9">
        <memberName>Josh</memberName>
    </selectName>
    <selectName num="10">
        <memberName>Buckethead</memberName>
    </selectName>
</selectlist>
```

XSL Code(the part in bold is responsible for drop down menu):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:for-each select="/selectlist/selectName">
    <option VALUE="{memberName}">
        <xsl:value-of select="memberName"/>
    </option>
</xsl:for-each>

</xsl:stylesheet> `
```

Please excuse me if I actually haven't noticed something obvious, i'm just a beginner at web development, and xslt is giving me a hard time. Help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can not just put the `for-each` in the stylesheet, it needs to be part of a template.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="/selectlist">
    <xsl:for-each select="selectName">
        <option VALUE="{memberName}">
            <xsl:value-of select="memberName"/>
        </option>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet> `
```